# Spring-JPA-Hibernate-controlled transactions using @Transactional: error injection possible?

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing, jpa, error-handling

I'm using the `@Transactional` annotation on my `MessageHook.onMessage()` implementation. The interface is from Apache James and I'm running a `SMTP` server using Netty.

What I want to do: I want to make sure that I get *temporary* smtp error codes from the SMTP lib when there is a problem with the database, for example with the database commit. I want to write a test for that scenario to make sure the SMTP lib behaves correctly. Is there any intended way to do that? Preferred solution would be to tell Spring or the underlying database driver to simulate a commit error.

**Does Spring provide such a functionality**? Or is there any Hibernate-compatible in-memory database that provides it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for an integration test that tests the behavior of your SMTP code when a call to a Spring injected service  fails?

Comment: no, I want to ensure that the framework delivers the result I need....  example: AOP and transaction handling. The commit gets handled *after* my onMessage() code has been run. If that fails, I want to make sure that the commit error gets handled correctly by the SMTP lib. What could go wrong: AOP in some situations drops exceptions and does not propagate them upwards. It does not seem to be the case here atm, but I want to detect upstream changes that may change that behaviour in the future....

Comment: I looked at the Spring transaction handling code and the method description says that it throws the exception from the called method (onMessage() in my case), but obviously it also throws any Exceptions generated by commit/rollback errors ... but that is not documented there. If you can point me to an API document snippet that ensures a specific behaviour regarding commit/rollback/db errors when using Spring's @Transactional, I could possibly drop that work and rely on it. In the meantime I'm writing a stub for a JDBC data source that let's me inject errors at begin/commit/rollback time.